# javascript library to show photo album

Tags: javascript

I visited few web sites in the past where they had a set of photo thumbnails and clicking on one of them created a cool effect of an expanding popup showing the full size image.
Is there any available free JavaScript library that will do this?

I'm interested mostly in the popup effect and less in the rest of the album management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightbox is another popular one:
[Lightbox Project Page](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: Lightbox `minified` version is only `9.5kb`...

Answer (score 2):

The [thickbox plugin](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) for [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) will do what you want.

Comment: This link is `gone`....

Comment: [THICKBOX](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/).  The currently active link...

Answer (score 0):

check out jQuery http://jquery.com

and then the LightBox plugin for jQuery: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/